# XyPic xymatrix not showing arrow labels with TeX Live-2012

Tags: diagrams, texlive, arrows, xy-pic

Recently I have upgraded my TeX installation to TeX Live-2012 from TeX Live-2009. Now `\xymatrix` is misbehaving. The behavior affects both Mac OS X and Ubuntu Linux 12.04 installations.

For example, the straightforward code

```
\[
  \xymatrix{
  F \ar[r]^-v \ar[dr]_-{T v} & V \ar[d]^-T \\
  & W }
\]
```

used to label the arrows correctly, now has the bizarre effect of

```
\[
  \xymatrix{
  F^v_{T v} \ar[r] \ar[dr] & V^T \ar[d] \\
     & W }
\]
```

Here's my preamble:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{letter}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage[urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
```

Has anyone encountered this unexpected behavior?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Why should the syntax `\usepackage[all]{xy}` be obsolete? It isn't. The `breqn` package is the culprit.

Comment: Edited. If you know that some syntax isn't obsolete and say so explicitly, what is the point of asking why it should be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't say from what TeX distribution you upgraded. The `breqn` package has undergone big changes, one of which, unfortunately, makes it not to cooperate well with Xy-pic.

You can return to the normal behavior with some trick:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{letter}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

%%% breqn changes the category code of ^ and _
%%% in a way that breaks Xy-pic
\newcommand{\Xycatcodes}{\catcode`\^=7 \catcode`\_=8 }
\makeatletter
\preto\xymatrix@setup{\Xycatcodes}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
  \xymatrix{
  F \ar[r]^-v \ar[dr]_-{T v} & V \ar[d]^-T \\
  & W }
\]
\end{document}
```

It's possible that other characters give problems, but this should work. The change is localized to `\xymatrix` so it should be possible to use it in `breqn` environments.

The syntax

```
\usepackage[all]{xy}
```

is *not* obsolete at all. It's the other way around: one should never use

```
\input xy
\xyoption{all}
```

in LaTeX.

Comment: The last remark is incorrect--it is permissible to use the earlier form in Latex 2e, e.g., if you want backwards compatibility with v2.